# how to merge two or more list in custom order in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd


y = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\vibhu\\Desktop\\Training docs\\excel training\\super store data transformation\\Sample - Superstore data transformation by Vaibhav.xlsx')
superstore_orders = y.parse(sheet_name='Orders Input data')

superstore_orders.dtypes

factual_table= superstore_orders[['Order ID','Customer ID','Postal Code','Product ID','Product Name','Sales','Quantity','Discount','Profit' ]]

Order_table= superstore_orders[['Order ID','Order Date','Ship Date','Ship Mode']]
Order_table1= Order_table.drop_duplicates(subset='Order ID', keep='first', inplace=False)
Customer_table= superstore_orders[['Customer ID','Customer Name','Segment']]
Customer_table1= Customer_table.drop_duplicates(subset='Customer ID', keep='first', inplace=False)
Geographical_table= superstore_orders[['Postal Code','Country','City','State','Region']]
Geographical_table1= Geographical_table.drop_duplicates(subset='Postal Code', keep='first', inplace=False)
Product_table= superstore_orders[['Product ID','Category','Sub-Category','Product Name']]
Product_table1= Product_table.drop_duplicates(subset=['Product ID','Product Name'], keep='first', inplace=False)

Final_factual_data = pd.merge(Order_table1, factual_table, how='left', on='Order ID')
Final_factual_data = pd.merge(Customer_table1, Final_factual_data, how='left', on='Customer ID')
Final_factual_data = pd.merge(Geographical_table1,Final_factual_data,how='left', on='Postal Code')
Final_factual_data = pd.merge(Product_table1,Final_factual_data,how='left', on=['Product ID','Product Name'] )

Output is this format:-     Product ID  Category    Sub-Category    Product Name    Postal Code Country City    State   Region  Customer ID Customer Name   Segment Order ID    Order Date  Ship Date   Ship Mode   Sales   Quantity    Discount    Profit
```

I require reformatting in this order :

**Order ID  order date  ship date   ship mode   Customer ID cutomer name    segment Postal Code country     city    state   reion   Product ID  Product Name    product key     cateory subcategory Sales   Quantity    Discount    Profit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final_factual_data1 = Final_factual_data [['Order ID','Order Date','Ship Date','Ship Mode','Customer ID','Customer Name','Segment','Country','City','State','Postal Code','Region','Product ID','Category','Sub-Category','Product Name','Sales','Quantity','Discount','Profit']]

this code help me to get the desired answer

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the intended ordered sequence to `columns` attribute:

```
Final_factual_data.columns = ['Order ID', 'order date', 'ship date', 'ship mode', 'Customer ID', 'cutomer name', 'segment', 'Postal Code', 'country', 'city', 'state reion', 'Product ID', 'Product Name', 'product key', 'cateory', 'subcategory', 'Sales', 'Quantity', 'Discount', 'Profit']
```

Comment: it will rename the columns but data remain the same. I need to change the whole column with data.